# ImportError: No module tinytest on a django application

Tags: python

I am learning form submission using AJAX.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from forms import tinyFormTest
from .models import tinytest
from django.shortcuts import render

# Index page view --
def home(request):
    form = tinyFormTest()
    context =  {
        'form' : form,
    }
    return render(request, 'form.html', context)
```

Comment: Is there a directory called `models` next to the file causing the error containing a file calle`tinytest.py`?

Answer (score 0):

there is no directory called models but there will be a file called models.py in your project folder and tinytest should be a model in that